# Angular: Difference between ./assets and /assets

Tags: html, angular

So, I have this Angular code base where both `./assets/...` and `/assets/....` paths are used interchangeably in HTML (`<img src='...'>`) and CSS (`background: url(...)`) files.

The issue is, after exporting the app with `--base-href=http://localhost/path/`, some resources (images) resolve with `http://localhost/path/assets/...` while the other resolve with `http://localhost/assets/...` (resolving to the top directory on the server). I am unable to pin-point this behaviour.

I can surely put a dot in front of the resources with the pattern `/assets/...`, but how come they are working fine in the first place i.e. resolving correctly to `http://localhost/path/assets/...`? The behaviour is ambiguous. Any ideas?

Comment: `some resources expect http://localhost/path/assets/...`.. What resources?

Comment: @PrasunJajodia resources like Images

Comment: when referencing assets, use `/assets` everywhere instead of `./assets` or `assets`.. Everything should work if you're consistent with `/assets`

Comment: It's not my personal project. So people have used whatever they deemed fit at that moment (short sighted decision, ikr) when they were writing new code.

Comment: Normally, `./assets` will not work if you're not in the root. i.e. It will work for `http://localhost` but not for `http://localhost/somepath`. With `--base-href`, it might be different. check out https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6730

Answer (score 2):

i gonna explain it, but I recommend you to take a look at the documentation of angular.io

to define the base href:
[Click Here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag)

"./assets" -> Relative URL, in angular always is the [Base Href](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag)

"/assets" -> It's a absolute url Trying to get from the root of the domain

Relative -> mydomain.com/my/app/assets

Absolute -> mydomain.com/assets